# Make ViewModel Wait for Views Async to Complete (Combine)

Tags: swift, mvvm, combine

I need a way to make a ViewModel wait for a View's async operation to complete before continuing while keeping context.

The view has a reference to the ViewModel but the ViewModel does not have a reference to the view, instead the view is updated via binding using Combine.

There are plenty of cases where this problem could apply, one such is:

```
protocol ViewModelInterface: ObservableObject {
  associatedtype Model: ModelInterface
  
  var model: Model { get set }
}

class SplashViewModel: ViewModelInterface {
  internal var model: Model
  private let authProvider: AuthProvider

  @Published internal var viewState = ViewState()

  init(model: Model, authProvider: AuthProvider) {
    self.model = model
    self.authProvider = authProvider

    guard let refreshToken = keychain.refreshToken else {
      viewState.isPlayingAnimation = true
      //Need to wait for animation to finish before routing to screen B
      return
    }

    authProvider.login(refreshToken: refreshToken)
    .onSuccess { [weak self] _ in
      self?.viewState.isPlayingAnimation = true
      //Need to wait for animation to finish before routing to screen A
    }.onFailure { [weak self] error in
      self?.viewState.isPlayingAnimation = true
      //Need to wait for animation to finish before routing to screen B
    }
  }
}
```

```
import Combine

class View<M>: UIView where M: ViewModelInterface {
  @IBOutlet var view: UIView! //Set via Xib

  internal let viewModel: M
  internal var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  required init(viewModel: M) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    
    //Constrain view to self    

    viewModel.objectWillChange
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .sink(receiveValue: refresh)
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  internal func refresh(output: M.ObjectWillChangePublisher.Output) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

```
import Lottie

class SplashView: View<SplashViewModel> {
  var animation: AnimationView?

  required init(viewModel: SplashViewModel) {
    super.init(viewModel: viewModel)
    setupAnimation()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  override func refresh(output: Void) {
    super.refresh(output: output)
    refreshAnimation()
  }

  func refreshAnimation() {
    if viewModel.viewState.isPlayingAnimation {
      animation?.play()
    } else {
      animation?.stop()
    }
  }

  func setupAnimation() {
    //Configure animation and constrain to view
  }
}
```

In this situation it uses the authProvider to make a call for a new access token using the refresh token, then once the request comes back it plays a short animation before routing to the next screen. If the user cannot be authenticated then it goes to screen B, if the user successfully authenticates then it goes to screen A.

My question is how can the ViewModel be made to only do the appropriate routing once the Views animation completes?
The View could call a function on the ViewModel to tell it that the animation has completed, however if we use that approach then the ViewModel loses context on what particular leaf in the decision tree caused the animation in the first place and therefore it won't know what screen to route to.

We can solve this by storing every single possible decision the logic flow could take in a struct, then setting those values and reading them. However that would be very messy and I don't think it's a good solution.

But how else can this be done?

Comment: If you made the viewmodel own the animation configuration like delay and time, you could tell the ViewModel to delay the exact amount of time before triggering the view state change.

Or you could tell the view to listen for changes to view state and trigger navigation after the animation is complete.


If you post your view logic here, that would be helpful in providing you a more exact answer.

Comment: @Jake I've updated it to include view logic.